# Displaying specific id or class in another id by clicking on a link

Tags: jquery, html

I have these links

```
<a href="#home">Home</a>
<a href="#about">About</a>
<a href="#portofolio">Portofolio</a> 
<a href="#contact">Contact</a>
```

I want the user to click on any of these and have same div id display in another div. Plus I want the first child to be removed.

```
<section id="part" class="part">
<div id="home"class="home">first Content </div>
<div id="about"class="about"><p>Another type of information</p></div>      
<div id="portofolio"class="portofolio"><p>oh heres another</p></div>      
<div id="contact"class="contact"><p>aaaand another one</p></div>      
</section>
```

I'm using jquery to do that, however I'm not getting there. I'm sure you guys know better.

https://jsfiddle.net/xm8sLcuy/

above is what I have here
I appreciate it in advance.

Comment: can you please post a JSfiddle ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xm8sLcuy/

does this help?

Comment: see the JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xm8sLcuy/1/ what you wna tnext ? which is this another DIV ?

Comment: I want when I click on any link, the link would should the same div in the section. I mean section should be empty till you click on any link which will lead you to show same id content in that secont

Comment: now check the JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xm8sLcuy/5/

Comment: can i post it as an answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the script below

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#part").find("div").hide();

$("a").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var divID = $(this).attr("href");
  var result = divID.substring(divID.length, 1);
  $("#part").find("div").hide();    
  $("#"+result).show();
});

});
```

See the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xm8sLcuy/5/) also.

Hope this helps.